# MVC 4 and lazy loading: "Collection was modified" error when deleting multiple records

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

In ASP.NET MVC 4 project, I have a model `LeagueMember`:

```
public class LeagueMember
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int LeagueId { get; set; }

    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual League League { get; set; }

    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

}
```

In League model, I have:

```
public virtual ICollection<LeagueMember> LeagueMembers { get; set; }
```

In the `Edit` view of `League` controller, I have a dropdown for `LeagueMembers` and in its Edit action I am trying to delete existing LeagueMembers and creating new ones:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(LeagueMembersViewModel leagueMemberViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var league = leagueMemberViewModel.League;
        context.Entry(league).State = EntityState.Modified;

        /* without this line the next foreach statement would complain that 
           League.LeagueMembers is null due to lazy loading..*/
        context.Entry(league).Collection("LeagueMembers").Load();

        var leagueMembers = leagueMemberViewModel.League.LeagueMembers;

        foreach (var leagueMember in leagueMembers)
        {
            context.LeagueMembers.Remove(leagueMember);
        }

        foreach (var memberId in leagueMemberViewModel.SelectedMembers)
        {
            var leagueMember = new LeagueMember { MemberId = memberId, League = league };
            context.LeagueMembers.Add(leagueMember);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }

    leagueMemberViewModel.MemberList = new MultiSelectList(context.Members, "Id", "Name", leagueMemberViewModel.SelectedMembers);
    return View(leagueMemberViewModel);
}
```

When executed, the line `foreach (var leagueMember in leagueMembers)` complains on second iteration of forloop:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Is there a better way to delete bulk records in a one-to-many relationship?

In this case, *to Remove All `leagueMemberViewModel.League.LeagueMembers`* perhaps without iterating through the collection?

Something like, replacing:

```
context.Entry(league).Collection("LeagueMembers").Load();

var leagueMembers = leagueMemberViewModel.League.LeagueMembers;
foreach (var leagueMember in leagueMembers)
{
    context.LeagueMembers.Remove(leagueMember);
}
```

with:

```
 leagueMember.League.LeagueMembers.Remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code has some typos. For example, it looks like `var league = leagueMember.League` should be `var league = leagueMemberViewModel.League`. Reading between the lines I suspect that `leagueMembers` is the same as the leagueMembers of the attached `league` object. (That you attach by setting `EntityState.Modified`).

If so, the error is explained by the fact that you loop through a loaded collection and at the same time remove items from it. The remedy is simple:

```
foreach (var leagueMember in leagueMembers.ToArray()) // <= ToArray
```

which copies the collection to a local array that does not change.

As for your second question: no there is no built-in way to do bulk deletes in Entity Framework.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your answer. I have corrected the typo. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a collection while iterating through it, the best approach is to use a reverse for loop like this:

```
        for (int i = leagueMembers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            context.LeagueMembers.Remove(leagueMembers[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a common .NET error, you can get around this by replacing your `foreach` loop with a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < leagueMembers.Count; i++)
{
    context.LeagueMembers.Remove(leagueMembers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not .NET error. The collection IS modified! Your method won't work because LeageMembers is ICollection and hence index operator cant be used.